Did Hitler say "I cannot live if one Jew is left"?
Recently, Moshe Feiglin, former deputy speaker of Israel's Knesset, said something on Israeli TV that went viral on X (Formerly Twitter): (see this and this)

"As Hitler said, 'I cannot live if one Jew is left,' we can't live here if one 'Islamo-nazi' remains in Gaza.”

Did Hitler really say "I cannot live if one Jew is left"?
similar post: Did Hitler say: "I would have killed all the Jews of the world, but I kept some to show the world why I killed them"?

Some sources give a slightly different translation "I cannot live in this world if there is one Jew left in it". None of the reports give a source for the quote in Hitler, and I can't find anything resembling it in English-language books, but it's hard to know what the German original might be.

Curious, is Moshe Feiglin comparing himself to Hitler?
